# Vue Js Components does not get destroyed?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

I'm currently working on an very versatile dashboard to display various data.

For the frontend I'm using the latest nuxt and vue version.

My dashboard has many kinds of variations to display data (for example pie charts, line charts,...) these are described in components which are called dynamically.

The Problem is that when I browse from the Page "/" to another (for example "/foo") the interval gets fired again and crashes the app.
That happenes after the lifecycle hook destroyed. I tried to define the interval as an variable and stop it in the beforeDestroy hook but it did not help.

```
let interval= setInterval(this.fetchData.bind(null, configuration, connector), configuration.refreshTime)

/* later */
clearInterval(interval);
```

Do you see an error?

Thank you.

---

Thats the relevant code:

Template

```
<no-ssr>
  <v-container grid-list-md>
    <v-layout row wrap v-masonry transition-duration="0.5s" item-selector=".flex" column-width="#grid-sizer">
      <v-flex xs1 sm1 md1 lg1 x1 id="grid-sizer"></v-flex>
      <component :key="dashboardItem.id" v-for="(dashboardItem,index) in dashboardItems" :is="dashboardItem.type" :connector="dashboardItem.connector"
        :type="dashboardItem.type" :configuration="dashboardItem.configuration" :id="dashboardItem.id" :index="index"></component>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</no-ssr>
```

Script

```
import OnlyValue from '@/components/dashboardItems/OnlyValue.vue'
import TrafficLight from '@/components/dashboardItems/TrafficLight.vue'
import ChartAllHover from '@/components/dashboardItems/ChartAllHover.vue'
import PieChart from '@/components/dashboardItems/PieChart.vue'
import Section from '@/components/dashboardItems/Section.vue'
import Gauge from '@/components/dashboardItems/Gauge.vue'...    
export default {
  name: 'HomePage',

  head () {
    return {
      title: "Dashboard"
    }
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      isAuthenticated: "users/isAuthentificated",
      profileName: "profiles/name",
      dashboardItems: "profiles/dashboardItems"
    })
  },

  mounted() {
    if (typeof this.$redrawVueMasonry === 'function') {
      this.$redrawVueMasonry()
    }
  },

  components: {
    OnlyValue,
    TrafficLight,
    ChartAllHover,
    PieChart,
    Section,
    Gauge
  }
}
```

When calling a components it looks the following:

```
import dashboardItem from '~/mixins/dashboardItem'

export default {
name: "gauge",

mixins: [dashboardItem],

props: {
    connector: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    type: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    configuration: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
    },
    id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    index: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
  },

  data: () => ({
    initOptions: {
        renderer: 'svg'
    },
    options: {
      tooltip: {
        formatter: "{c}%"
      },
      series: [{
        name: null,
        type: 'gauge',
        detail: {
          formatter: '{value}%'
        },
        data: null
      }]
    },
    isLoading: true
  }),

  methods: {
    getData(configuration, connector) {
      this.fetchData(configuration, connector)
      setInterval(this.fetchData.bind(null, configuration, connector), configuration.refreshTime)
    },
    fetchData(configuration, connector) {
      this.getSingleValue(configuration, connector)
        .then(data => {
          this.isLoading = false
          let percent = (data.value / configuration.max) * 100
          percent = Math.round(percent * 10) / 10
          this.$nextTick(function () {
            this.$refs.gauge.mergeOptions({
              series: [{
                name: data.title,
                data: [{
                  value: percent,
                  name: data.title
                }]
              }]
            })
          })
          this.$redrawVueMasonry()
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e))
    }
  },

  mounted () {
    this.getData(this.configuration, this.connector)
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you defining the interval? Are you saving the interval handle to data?

Comment: Hi Bert, see the last code box => methods => getData(). The Inverval fires the function fetchData() and processes the data then for the dashboard item.

Comment: Add a data property to store the interval, say `fetchDataInterval` and then in `fetchData`, store the interval: `this.fetchDataInterval = setInterval(...)`. Then in `beforeDestroy`, call `clearInterval(this.fetchDataInterval)`.